# How do you change the value of a global variable from a function in Kotlin?

Tags: global-variables, kotlin

This code:

```
var number: Int = 0;

fun increaseNumber(): Int {
    number = 1;
    return number;
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(number);
}
```

Yields this output:

```
0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How do you change the value of a global variable in Kotlin?

Comment: As @PixelElephant says you have to actually call the function. Further your function is probably not doing what you really want. It is not increasing the number but always setting it to 1 regardless of the previous value of `number`. The behavior you likely want is `number += 1` or shorter `number++` which takes the current value of the number and increments it by 1. So now when you call `increaseNumber` 5 times the value of number will be 5, where before it would have always been 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually call your function:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    increaseNumber()
    println(number)
}
```